# Repair an SSD that's been unplugged during Secure Erase

Tags: ssd, repair, secure-erase

I used to have some issue with a SanDisk X110 mSATA SSD and I put it on a Secure Erase using TxBench, with a USB adapter implemented with ASM1053E chip. Very unfortunately my PC got stuck after a few seconds and I removed the SSD. Now the USB adapter works fine (undamaged) but whenever I plug in the SSD (either USB or SATA) and try to operate, every software that accesses it gets stuck and returns to normal as soon as I remove the SSD. I can neither format the SSD nor erase it again. TxBench tells me it's not security frozen but fails to erase it. Is there any way to rescue the SSD and make it function normally?
Note: With the word "repair" I mean I just want the drive back, no data recovery (I always keep a good backup)

Edit: I believe the drive is *not* broken because I can see it's model number in Windows Disk Management **and** all software can identify the disk (but without capacity) **and** HD Tune & Crystal Disk Info can read all its SMART data correctly.

Comment: You may find the disk firmware is just busy doing the erase. Try leaving it powered on for a few hours to see if it eventually finishes and starts accepting commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ATA Secure Erase doesn't work over USB](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase):

> **WARNING: Do not attempt to do this through a USB interface!** This procedure worked fine when I tried it on my X-25M through the SATA interface. When I tried it again later on the same drive through a USB adapter, it let me password protect the drive, but would not accept the SECURITY-ERASE command.

It is possible that your USB enclosure is blocking I/O because it is unable to cope with your SSD that has an ATA password set on it.  The drive won't answer read requests, so the enclosure might be unsuccessfully trying and retrying accesses forever.

There is a decent chance you can fix this by plugging in the SSD directly through the motherboard's SATA interface.

Once the SSD is connected directly by SATA, try disabling the password.

On Linux, the command to do this is

```
sudo hdparm --security-disable PASSWORD /dev/sdX
```

… where `PASSWORD` is the password you originally set and `/dev/sdX` is the SSD.

Comment: What should I do if I don't know the password at all? It's security frozen and after a hot plug it turns to security locked.

Comment: @iBug: The [TxBENCH documentation](http://www.texim.jp/txbenchus.html) says that they have a [password removal tool](http://www.texim.jp/dl/RemovePwd.zip).

Comment: To correct you, there _are_ some USB-SATA adapter chips that support ATA PASS-THROUGH command, which enables all ATA operation through USB interface.

Answer (score 0):

A SSD is very different from a HDD.
You do not need to do a secure erase on a SSD, in fact it is counterproductive. When you just delete all items or format the drive, and then let it connected for a (short) while, the built-in GarbageCollection will free up all deleted bits, and after that there is no way to recover any data.
To get it back after your action, just connect and format it again.